# Parsing string in reports gives "#Error" when value is null

Tags: reporting-services

SQL is returning strings containing Expr1>....

This is my expression:

```
 =iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " "   , 
                      Mid(Fields!Teams.Value,InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,",")+1,(InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,"<") - InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,",")-1)))
```

This expression works to parse all my values EXCEPT for null.

I tried this:

```
=iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, "empty"  , Fields!Teams.Value)
```

and it takes the null values correctly.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: In the first example you aren't giving it a then condition.  Try this. =iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, 0 , 
                      Mid(Fields!Teams.Value,InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,",")+1,(InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,"<") - InStr(Fields!Teams.Value,",")-1)))

Comment: Sorry, I did put this " " I should edit my question.

Comment: Have you tried the ISNOTHING(Fields!Teams.Value) way?

Comment: Yeah that too returns a #Error, ISNothing(Fields!Teams.Value)  and ISNothing(Fields!Teams.Value) = true too

Comment: I think what's happening is that ssrs validates the whole string. As a test try this. =iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " ",Mid(iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " ",Fields!Teams.Value),InStr(iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " ",Fields!Teams.Value),",")+1,(InStr(iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " ",Fields!Teams.Value),"<") - InStr(iif(Fields!Teams.Value= nothing, " ",Fields!Teams.Value),",")-1)))

Comment: Might need to change '' " after the first one to a number.

Comment: mhm still nothing